# Android Camera2 API Focus Distance Calibration

Tags: android, camera-calibration

Currently I have a Nexus 9 that returns a value of "Approximated" when

```
mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION)
```

is called.  My question is...what devices are out there that allows for a "Calibrated" device?  Or is there a way I can calibrate the camera?  An accurate focus distance is very helpful for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus 6 has a lens that reports `CALIBRATED`. It is the only one I know of at the moment. You can see a helpful database of device capabilities which I am trying to compile [here](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~rcsumner/devcam/devicedatabase.html).

There is no way for you to change the camera device's status to `CALIBRATED`, it is a manufacturer/hardware level issue.